# Hyperlinks blocked in Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, group-policy, hyperlink

Office 2013 gives me the message "Your organization's policies are preventing us from completing this action for you.  For more info, please contact your help desk." whenever I try to click on a hyperlink.  Word Outlook and Excel are all doing it.  I have tried several online suggestions to no avail.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled my browsers.  I have reset group policies.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled office.  I have set up a new user.  This is a stand alone machine that has never been on a domain network.  It was working fine until last summer.

I have looked at editing the Registry key :Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\C‌​ommon\Internet\UseOn‌​lineContent When I get down to "Internet" "useOnlineContent" is not an option.

I have now tried editing the registry.  I changed all the html keys to have the value htmlfile.  Still not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and fail I started analyzing the common points in the online suggestions.  Everything seemed to come back to having uninstalled Firefox while it was the default browser.  My son had done this when he borrowed my computer for a few days.  There was a suggestion to make Internet Explorer the default browser but Windows10 has Edge and making Edge the default didn’t work even if it was the only browser.  You would think reinstalling Firefox and making it default again would work but it didn’t.
What ended up working was to install Internet Explorer and make it the default.  Then uninstall any other browsers.  Restart.  Once the links are working with IE you can reinstall the other browsers and make any one of them the default.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SOOO MUCH!
That is the solution.
I want to add here for all who struggle with applying this fix.

You can not install IE (Internet Explorer) just like that if Edge (browser) is already installed, which usually is the case, because the IE installer complains that there is already a newer version installed (meaning Edge).
You also can not simply uninstall Edge! It is just not possible. THANK YOU MICROSOFT!
So you have to go to the "Turn Windows features on or off" window, which you can access on the left panel in the "Programs and Features" (the classic Windows software uninstall page).
There you have the option to activate IE again as a Windows feature.
Once that is done (just check the box and close the window with OK) and the computer has restarted you can select the IE as default browser and the links in mails in Outlook (2013) are working again.
Then you can choose any browser as default that you want and do not even have to restart Outlook. :-)

I guess I ran into the issue, because one day I just thought to myself I need some space on my system drive and just clean out old Windows components I do not need and which seem to be a security risk (IE) anyway.
Wrong. --> Never change a running System. :-D